# WordPress notification e-mail when new comment is placed

Tags: wordpress, plugins, comments

I'm wondering if it is possible to let subscribers on my WordPress blog get notified by e-mail when a new comment is placed on a post where they have commented on. Basically this is kinda like when Facebook gives you a notification when someone else posted a comment on something you follow/like/commented on. I've been searching for a plugin that let's me configure such an e-mail, but no success yet.

Any help or suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Please try [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-comment-notifications/) plugin for your purpose.